# trigger throwing error when calling future apex class

Tags: apex, trigger

I am having a class which has future annotation and I am calling that apex class through a trigger then trigger is giving me below error.

"Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void relatedtows(Id) from the type RelatedTowtoContact"

My Class:

```
public class RelatedTowtoContact {
@future(callout =true)
public static void relatedtows(List<Id> alltows123){
    List<Related_TOW__c> allrelatedtows = [select Id, Name, Lead__c, Contact__c,Tow_Id__c from Related_TOW__c where Id IN: alltows123];
    set<Id> contactid = new set<Id>();
    set<Id> leadId = new set<Id>();
    for(Related_TOW__c tow: allrelatedtows){
        //------------------------------------------//
        if(tow.Lead__c != NULL){
        //if(tow.Contact__c != null){
            leadId.add(tow.Lead__c);
        //}
    //}
    system.debug('contactId is :' + contactid);
    Map<Id, Lead> leadMap = new Map<Id,Lead>([select Id, Related_TOW_IDs__c from Lead where Id IN : leadId]);
    List<Lead> updatelead = new List<Lead>();
    system.debug('leadMap is :' + leadMap);
    for(Related_TOW__c t : allrelatedtows){
        if(leadMap.get(t.Lead__c).Related_TOW_IDs__c == null){
            leadMap.get(t.Lead__c).Related_TOW_IDs__c = t.Tow_Id__c;
            system.debug('related tow is : ' + leadMap.get(t.Lead__c).Related_TOW_IDs__c);
        }
        else{
            leadMap.get(t.Lead__c).Related_TOW_IDs__c = leadMap.get(t.Lead__c).Related_TOW_IDs__c + ';' + t.Tow_Id__c;
        }
       // updatecon.add(conMap);
    }
    update leadMap.values();
        }
```

Trigger:

```
trigger TowIdtoContact on Related_TOW__c (After insert, After Update) {
for(Related_TOW__c tow: trigger.new){
    RelatedTowtoContact.relatedtows(tow.Id);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing an Id as a parameter to your apex class method where it accepts a list. Do following it will resolve the issue.

```
trigger TowIdtoContact on Related_TOW__c (After insert, After Update) {
   for(Related_TOW__c tow: trigger.new){
       RelatedTowtoContact.relatedtows(new List<Id>{tow.Id});
   }
}
```

Comment: I updated the code but still getting the same issue again

Comment: Is your apex class saved and there are no errors. Some time there are errors due to which latest changes are not saved.